# Do not display use element created through javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, svg

i have a svg file. JavaScript a create 'use' tag on 'window.onload'. 
But image in use do not display in the browser.

What could be the problem?

PS. Sorry for my English.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:mpc="http://www.crtc.com/mpclogic" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <g id="elem">
        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAARCAYAAAA/mJfHAAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH2QgYDDQJl9RhwQAAAshJREFUOMutlN9LU2EYx98zj85hZKZN1zRxvzQRiuE/MIh+MQKv1A2J3aRSNwZDvAhMlF0Iw19DXYJeKHSXbsokXZAcvRDnnDY9K5fr7EzP5kwRbfOc82xdFWkuKfrevc/74cPD8z68CKXIWkuLwN/UJEB/Efy84gelEpOrVBqcZZMIoXfoX7Mhk2XGR0Yegs8XBJdrKBXHOhwZURzHUoqWy8sF7NRUFXi9bnC5xmJ6veossy8QYJzdngvz80ZwOJTnitbl8kx2bu4++HxB2NyM8SsrL4/r6vLOclxNzU2gqNeJaPQrhEJv2drawt86jA8NPQCvdwkoagzW19uAJAP87GxbVCIRIoRQFMexk5oaMQSDExAOe4EgnsHOzgJQ1Ajf21t2egaDg3dhcbErJBbnekpLMziCeAEk+YV3Op8f63S5nE5XBhQ1Cnt7R+B0tm/IZDhvsdwGhvFAKDT9rbr62k9ZSCxOD+bnZ/04b0mlVzmn8ylEIgHeZjMBTduAYdaApichHPbFh4fveBWKdBgYuAfBoP2wtbUC+9PLbtXXC28YDJ1IoahDicR+cny8GVjWjWu1zUm//yhgMLRL5fIDXibLWyDJ3ZQiJjsb48xmCdC0AyKRT7C7S/M2m4mSSEQxq1UckUiKV0tLTy11ys74vj4FptW2IKGwImm3dyC5vBKTSh8nlpc7+cPDUVFDw8GFS7uTk4Nx3d3XgaYngWE8nF5fGddo0j4XFl45sVgagSS3gCBMVEGB6EIZ19VVAoHAK2CYJbBaH/16t6pSiXiC6ACfj+InJhpPpqcvpxSd9PTkAU1PAcN4eItFHddo0s4y/qKibHZ4+AmQZICfmTERanXaubL4wIAKtrffg9VatSWVppznmlIp4mdmTOB2vyHU6vRzoWBBARbr77/Emc0Xfj0bJSUZH4uLs04VjUbjLaPRKET/Id8BDhJvjlXXvRYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="19" height="17"/>
    </g>
</defs>
<text x='10' y='10'>12332</text>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var linkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    window.onload= function(){
        var elemUse = document.createElementNS(linkNS, 'use');
        elemUse.setAttributeNS(linkNS, 'xlink:href', 'elem');
        elemUse.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '53');
        elemUse.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '21');
        elemUse.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'up_201_trackworking1');
        document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(elemUse);             
    }
</script>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the use element in the xlink namespace rather than the svg namespace so the correct code would look something like this...

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var linkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
window.onload= function(){
    var elemUse = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'use');
    elemUse.setAttributeNS(linkNS, 'xlink:href', 'elem');
```